# Get last part of CSV string

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

Say I have a CSV string:

```
red,yellow,green,blue
```

How would I programatically select `blue` from the string using jQuery?

The data is returned via an AJAX request from a PHP script rendering a CSV file.

```
var csv_Data;

$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'server.php',
    async: false,
    data: null, 
    success: function(text) { 
        csv_Data = text;
    } 
}); 

console.log(csv_Data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No jQuery, plain JavaScript:

```
var csv_Data = text.split(',');
var last = csv_Data[csv_Data.length - 1];
```

I strongly recommend against making synchronous calls.

**Reference:** [`string.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

**Update:** If you really only want to get the last value, you can use [`lastIndexOf` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and
[`substr` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
var last = text.substr(text.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);
```

Comment: @naveen: I assumed the whole data will be used later on. Of course if it is not needed anymore, `pop` is just fine.

Comment: all the data will be required at various steps +1 for thinking outside the box

Comment: @Xavier: out of the box as in rabbit out of the hat? please spend some time and ask what you want clearly to avoid out of the box solutions. remember, this is also a wiki. i didnt upvote felix since it will give the wrong idea to a future visitor :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop):

```
var lastValue = csv_Data.split(",").pop();  // "blue"
```

Answer (score 4):

Or even

```
var csv_data = text.substr(text.lastIndexOf(",") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery CSV plugin as per instructions [here](http://code.google.com/p/js-tables/wiki/CSV). However, CSV format usually has quotes around the values. It would be easier to send the data in JSON format from the PHP file using json_encode().